# EclipsePDT: how to add a Drupal project?

Tags: eclipse, drupal, drupal-6

how can I add an Eclipse project to my Eclipse PDT ?

I've a Drupal installation on my hard-disk (a subfolder of Eclipse workspace).

I've tried create new PHP project from eclipse, but it seems not to work.

I've successively tried to import the Drupal project but Eclipse only recognize the SimplyModern project from drupal themes folder, and not the main Drupal project.

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is the best tutorial i have came across.Hope it will help you...
[Setting up a local Drupal multisite in a Eclipse PDT environment](http://sites.google.com/site/drupaldebugmultisite/)

Answer (score 0):

Lot of links are available to configure Eclipse with PDT (start with https://drupal.org/node/75242). Once you have done that as well as the following
1. Enable XDebug extension in PHP and enable that as debugger for PHP in eclipse
2. Install Drupal Hooks plugin in Eclipse
3. Install Xtnd plugin for eclipse

Now, lets assume you have configured in your host file "mydrupalsite.com" to localhost and in httpd.conf you have pointed its docroot to drupal installation folder (parent directory of sites folder).

In Eclipse, window -> preferences set the PHP server to "http://mydrupalsite.com".

Create new php project, select option "from existing source" and point it to drupal installation directory mentioned above as docroot for http://mydrupalsite.com".

Once the project is included go to Run / Debug configurations of the project and select drupal's index.php present in the docroot to open. Deselect the option "Auto Generate URL" and let the URL be just "http://mydrupalsite.com"

Now to test the setup, place a breakpoint in index.php and run the project in debug mode.